# What does the "paper folded slightly up" symbol mean in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

In this screen shot, there is a symbol in the lower left corner of my image in the grid view. What is the significance of this symbol?

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The icon is telling you this image is a "virtual copy" of a master file. Virtual copies allow you to take a rendition into another direction, and can be based on any point in an image history, from import on.